# Accent insensitive in CriteriaBuilder query

Tags: java, jpa

Well, I'm using CriteriaBuilder and PredicateList to work with JPA and extract information from the database, the fact is that it contains data with accents and I need to do searches that even though I search without accents I find the words with accents too.
For example:
The database contains the following data:
'**técnico a**' means
'**tecnico b**'.

In the clause where I enter'**tec**' and I need both options to appear. How can I make him skip the accents? I need that the result will be:

tecnico a,
tecnico b

I have this code:

```
predicatesList.add((builder.like(builder.lower(root.<String>get("descripcion")),
                '%' + (descripcion.toLowerCase().trim() + '%'))));
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at how that is handled in your RDBMS; database specific. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144181/does-any-dbms-have-a-collation-that-is-both-case-sensitive-and-accent-insensitiv   When you work out how to do it in SQL then work out whether a JPQL function exists

Answer (score 0):

The point is that character 'é' and 'e' are different. So you can not find both if searching by one of them. Here is an idea that I just thought of. Make your table to hold two fields for description. Call one "description" and another "normilized_description" in the "description" store the original value in the "normilized_description" store the value where you will replace all accented characters with non-accented ones. So in your case your records will look like this: 
Record a:
description:'técnico a'
normilized_description: 'tecnico a'
 
Record b:
description:'tecnico b'
normilized_description: 'tecnico b'

Then if you need to search for both search by field "normilized_description" and if you need a specific value search by "description"

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried something like this but the only thing i can normalize is the string i collect to search, but where i want to remove the accents is in the strings of the database but i think it's impossible, i'm trying with CriteriaBuilder and jpa functions. Anyway, thank you for your interest.